# azure is it possible to create blob snapshot from user console

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

my question is about Microsoft Azure blob storage.

Can I manage blob snapshots from user console (azure portal)? Take snapshot,delete,recover etc.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by user console?

Comment: I mean azure portal (edited question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently the portal does not offer this functionality. You may want to check out Azure Explorers available in the market. Most of them have support for managing blob snapshots.

Comment: You can see some explorers here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/03/11/windows-azure-storage-explorers-2014.aspx